# How to Integrate Multiple Project Plans in a Weak Matrix Organization?

Tags: team-management, scrum, communication, ms-project

How can I approach integrating multiple project plans from different departments into one master plan? Here are the details in this situation:

- All teams are ultimately working on the same product, but each team works on their own smaller pieces.
- We have around 200 people working together.
- Knowledge is constantly being shared between departments.
- Each department (six total) has its own supervisor.
- I anticipate a challenge keeping the task information current, accurate, and useful for each department.
- For our IT development (25% of our overall project time), we have scrum sessions (no waterfall).
- Due to the nature of the work we do, the project planning must be rolling wave.
- We use Microsoft Project 2010 for project tracking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that you have different depts, teams and supervisors says that you're talking about a 'program' of sorts.

You haven't indicated what your role is in all this (PM, team member, CEO, etc), but it looks like the first step is putting someone in the role of Program Manager. Someone who's job is specifically to coordinate and track the various pieces as they relate to the whole.

As there are already dept supervisors you will face the authority (or lack of) issue, and it likely that the PgM will not have the needed authority to push certain aspects, but just having a central hub for tracking and reporting will go a long way.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree that this is a programme, and I believe that the biggest issue will be dealing with the different departments that all have their own perspective on the work. A professional Programme Office would be a great way to start, and with 200 people to be coordinated, I believe the justification for this would not be too difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Project Server **could** provide a centralized place for people place their MS Project 2010 files and share information. The system does have some pretty good consolidated master schedule views. I'm not in love with that solution, however, because there is some complexity in setting up a server.

There are [some hosted solutions](http://www.microsoft.com/project/en/us/on-demand-hosting.aspx) available but I have not yet tried any of them.

Answer (score 0):

In my company have gained a lot of experience in directing complex projects in weak matrix organizations. Please read through the white paper: "Who is your manager?" on the subject.

http://www.matan-consulting.com/uploadimages/PDF/Who%20is%20your%20managerWP.pdf